# Correct way to fetch data from an aws server into a flutter app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, fetch, aws-amplify

I have a general understanding question. I am building a flutter app that relies on a content library containing text files, latex equations, images, pdfs, videos etc.
The content lies on an aws amplify backend. Depending on the navigation of the user in the app, the corresponding data is fetched and displayed.

I am not sure about the correct way of fetching the data. The current method (which works) is that the data is stored in an S3 bucket. When data is requested, the data is downloaded to a temporary directory and then opened and processed in the app. This is actually not slow, but I feel that it is not the way it should be done.

When data is downloaded a file transfer notification pops up, which bothers me because it is shown all the time. Also I would like to read the data directly with something like a get request, without downloading the file first (specially for text files, which I would like to read directly into a String). But here I don't know how it works, because I don't see that you can save data in a file system with the other amplify services like data store or the rest api. Also, the S3 bucket is an intuitive way of storing data that is easy to use for the content creators of my company, for me it seems that the S3 bucket is the way to go.  However with S3 I have only figured out the download method to fetch data.

Could someone give me a hint on what is the correct approach for this use case? Thank you very much!

Comment: S3 is meant for object / file storage. You can't store strings, numbers, arrays in there. You can however store .txt files there, that you could read into a string. If this does not fit your need, you might be looking for a database rather than an object storage

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @JoRa, yes. I think that for most use cases I should use a database, I am working with DataStore right now.